# Is there a visual demo of Mercurial Merging, etc.?

Tags: mercurial

I am a very visual person and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around Source Control.

It would be really cool if there were a visual representation of what all the pieces look like (central repo, local, etc.) during the process.

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from reading this: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
Yeah it's for Git, but the same branching model can be applied to hg, and it shows the some ways you can share code between teams.